# read write synchronization in orient db

Tags: performance, orientdb

I have a doubt in orient db's read/write synchronization. I am not sure if this question is valid but I am pretty curious to know

1)  **why should a lock be acquired when I am reading a record** when orient db has a versioning system and it can, at any time, return the current version of the requested record?

I also observed that reading and writing completely different records is happening serially.

2)  Why should there be a shared lock when the records to be read and the records to be written are completely different?

3)   Even if the record to be updated is being read simultaneously why do we need the shared lock when the read can return the current version of the record?